# Structured vs. Unstructured Algorithm JavaScript

Tags: javascript, analysis

I wrote two functions to show numbers from 1 to 20 and tell which are multiples of 3, which are multiples of 5, which are of both and which aren't.

I decided to write the function that employs less time as possible.

I got these two function:

First one:

```
function func1(){
console.time('execution time:');

for ( var i=1 ; i<=20; i++)
    if((i%5)===0 && (i%3)===0)
      console.log("\n" + i + " : Multiple of 5 and 3.");
    else{
        if(i%3===0)
            console.log("\n" + i + " : Multiple of 3.");
        else{
            if(i%5===0)
        console.log("\n" + i + " : Multiple of 5.");
            else
                console.log("\n" + i);
        }
    }
console.timeEnd('execution time:');

}
```

The second one is:

```
function func2(){
    console.time('execution time:');

    for ( var i=1 ; i<=20; i++){

        if((i%5)===0 && (i%3)===0){
          console.log("\n" + i + " : Multiple of 5 and 3.");
          continue;
        }


        if(i%3===0){
            console.log("\n" + i + " : Multiple of 3.");
            continue;
        }

        if(i%5===0)
            console.log("\n" + i + " : Multiple of 5.");
        else
            console.log("\n" + i);

   }   

   console.timeEnd('execution time:');
}
```

The func1() has an execution time of: 29ms

The func2() has an execution time of: 20ms

The difference is huge about 1/3.

I have 2 questions:

1) Is it better compare i%5===0 before and then i%3===0 or viceversa?

2) The func2() have an execution time better than func1() but func2() have unstructured code becouse
    i have more than one exit point of the function (continue keyword is considered a go-to).
    The question is: Should i keep my structured code and ignore the execution time or, if i need a
    good performance, can i write this kind of code?

Comment: That's way too little execution time for anything to matter. The biggest time saving would be to memoize your division results (though the runtime *might* do that) instead of repeating `i%5` and `i%3` twice.

Comment: Your browser must be slow, mine uses 1.655 milliseconds, which is a little over one thousands of a second, so in other words it doesn't matter at all unless you intend to run the function a trillion times.

Comment: 20ms? On my computer, which is old and not very fast, it's 0ms. You should run it lots of times in order to compare.

Comment: With the reiterated caveat that optimizing code that does this little is pointless, what'd help a lot is to move those `console.log()` calls out of the tests. Have the tests build a string, and then put one `console.log()` call at the end of the loop to print out the result.

Comment: you are benchmarking the console more than the app logic. also, a third of not very much is not "huge". don't use percents on small amounts, that can be misleading. if one process takes 2ms and the other take 1ms, that means they are both instant, not that one is always half the speed of the other...

Comment: @dandavis i try on a larger intervall of numbers (1-2000) and the % isn't 1/3 like you said, is just 5-8% .
But the optimizing code with continue keyword is better for  readability and perfomance so you suggest me to write that code?

Comment: anything under a consistent 20% difference is basically just luck.

Comment: If you measure a 5-8% difference then *you don't need to optimize*. Choose the one to use based on which is the most readable, easiest to maintain and consistent with the rest of the code. Performance is the *last* thing you need to think about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the comments are right.  There are simply no particular performance considerations to worry about here.  So write code that's readable first.  How about something like this instead?:

```
function func3() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        var biz = (i % 3 === 0);
        var buzz = (i % 5 === 0);
        if (biz && buzz) {
            console.log("\n" + i + " : Multiple of 5 and 3");
        } else if (biz) {
            console.log("\n" + i + " : Multiple of 3");
        } else if (buzz) {
            console.log("\n" + i + " : Multiple of 5");
        } else {
            console.log("\n" + i);
        }            
    }
}
```

There is, in fact, one minor optimization already written into this code.  Since I know there are more multiples of 3 than of 5, I put the `biz` branch ahead of the `buzz` branch.  But I would not bother cluttering up the code with the other optimizations and use an ordering with `if (biz && ! buzz) ... if (buzz && ! biz) ... if (biz && buzz)`.  That optimization (if it is in fact actually one with the extra `&&`'s) would only be done later if I were to discover that this code is a performance bottleneck.

Comment: i have a clear idea now .. Thank you for the answer.